# I used the example gave by microsoft to drag and drop an object from a ScatteredView to a Surface List Box but it is not working

Tags: c#, listbox, drag-and-drop, pixelsense, scatterview

I developped the example given by Microsoft to drag and drop and object from a scatterview to a surface list box.

The scatterview is working, I can move the objects on it. But when I try to drag and drop them on the Surface ListBox nothing happen.

I posed a breakpoint on the method OnDragSourcePreviewContactDown but it doesn't enter in.

Anyone have an idea what could be the reason ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: here is the example I am working on :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804829%28v=Surface.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should post some code - I don't know MS example. Is it WPF you are using?

Then you may want to look at:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Drag_And_Drop_Sample.aspx

and

http://jasonrowe.com/2010/04/02/silverlight-drag-and-drop-with-rx/

and

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/J.Van.Gogh/Writing-your-first-Rx-Application/

Comment: Here is the example of Microsoft I am working on :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804829%28v=Surface.10%29.aspx